# How to validate a user during a web session?

Tags: security, session, client, server

Well, I have now implemented session handling but I am not quite sure how to work with that.

My concern is the following:

Let's say a user is logged in and wants to get a list of items from a specific store. So the client will send me an `id` for a store. That `id` will be linked to an actual id for a store entity that I use in my MySQL database. An intruder could just exchange that `id` and therefore receive back the "wrong" data from my server.

Here is my question: Is it enough to send the session ID over HTTPS inside the payload in order to be safe here? Is there anything else I **have to** consider if I don't want hostile users to be able to lure information from the server that they are not supposed to see? I am rather new to web development but I am writing on something that is supposed to become something like a commercial software in .. well someday :D but however, even if it was for the sake of learning something new, how is this done safely?

Comment: can you clarify this a little? I think you mean this is a multi-tenant application, and a user is, for example, a store manager (not just a customer)

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan Well, a user in this case is e.g. a registered person who owns a store and is able to add or remove his/her items. What I want to ensure is that the person who is sending the requests to my server is indeed the person who is allowed to. I know I can set cookies that might be able to identify somebody but afaik cookies alone are not enough. I was reading something about tokens that the server sends to the client in addition but I didn't really understand the whole process - how that really works and why I need such a token etc.

Comment: It's the first time I am implementing something like this so it is possible that I may appear kinda inept .. I just need to get over that hill to understand the security aspects behind this. I am using GWT that can handle some parts of that for me but I want to understand what happens behind the scenes in order to not make any mistakes that could harm my attempt to increase security.

Answer (score 0):

> An intruder could just exchange that id and therefore receive back the "wrong" data from my server.

You've presumably got in your database an association between users and stores. So when you get a request for store items, you check the passed store ID to see whether the current session's user is associated with the store. If the user is not authorised to view the store, you reject the request.

*Authentication* is only half the story. You need to do this kind of *authorisation* checking for every action a user can take in your application.

Comment: Yes, my question basically is how I could do that. Like I said in my comment on my question I know that one should exchange tokens? Tokens that the server generates and send to the client which has to send it back in order to be authorized for an action - or something like that. The thing is that I fail to understand the descriptions I've found so far and I'm not sure how I have to implement that. **1.** How to generate the token? **2.** How to exchange it *secure* between server/client. **3.** Are there pitfally? **4.** Anything else?

Comment: Another thing is - once the client got the token - why does this prevent me from becoming a victim of [CSRF/XSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)?

Comment: Who said anything about tokens? Signed tokens that represent a permission are certainly something that exists, but it's a complex and difficult approach to get right compared to the simple thing everyone does. Which is: on receiving a request to view a store, look up the owner of that store in your database and compare it to the user associated with the current session.

Comment: Similarly for XSRF, the typical approach is to put a random secret on the session, write it in forms, and require it to come back on form submissions. There are other approaches involving signing tokens, but if you already have a session you can store things like a current-user-ID and a XSRF-token on, you don't really need to bother with that.

Comment: That token thing is just something I read somewhere but didn't understand completely. Okay, well, if I got that right: I create a secret on the server e.g. just a random number. I send that to the client via HTTPS and it gets - as you said - injected as part of a submission? How would I do that for simple Hyperlinks? I can't just put that secret to GET parameters or something like that. The term "session" gets missused on some pages I guess because some pages refer to a cookie too as "session id" - but as we know - this is not save and might just be used as a login, right?

Comment: I'm sorry if my questions sound a little stupid but I just can't put the pieces together to get the whole picture. I think what I need is an example code for server/client - pseudo code will do fine - but I'm just not aware how to do that. Generating a random secret e.g. would mean that I store that secret in my database on the server. The server would have to look that up for each and every request, right?

Comment: You don't generally need XSRF protection on GET requests, as if you've designed your app properly GET requests never have any active effects (they're “idempotent”), so there's nothing an attacker can achieve by forcing a victim to do a GET request. Yes, in the model where you have server-side session storage you have to look it up from storage (the database or some in-memory caching scheme) for each request.

Comment: There are alternative methods with signed tokens that can authenticate without having to hit the DB each time but that's a bit more complicated and you don't get the ability to persist other storage on the session. Plus typically you're hitting the DB each time anyway to get user details and permissions. If you're new to this I suggest using an existing login and session framework before trying to write this kind of thing from scratch.

Comment: I'm now using [this](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideSecurityRpcXsrf.html) to protect the server from XSRF attacks. I still don't fully understand why exactly this protects me from that but .. yeah ..